# Can VBA detect line-wrapping in an Excel chart legend?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, legend-properties

**Context**

Writing to code to format a chart (all of which should be done by Microsoft, but that’s separate).

Am now positioning the legend. Taking a 9×9 block of possible positions, and counting the data points underneath each. As a fragment of the code: `(ax.MaximumScale - ax.MinimumScale) * co.Chart.Legend.Width / co.Chart.PlotArea.InsideWidth`.

Also coping with lines underlapping and text boxes overlapping the possible legend positions: same idea, more complexity.

**Question**

Obviously, all this works better if the legend is as small as possible, as that gives a greater likelihood of finding a location with zero ’lapping.

If .Legend.Width is too small, then the individual legend texts (the Series.Name’s) wrap onto ≥2 lines, which isn’t wanted. So VBA could interval bisect to find the smallest .Legend.Width for which there isn’t line wrapping. But how can the VBA code ‘see’|‘detect’|‘know’ of the existence of the line wrapping?

And *mutatis mutandis* for .Legend.Height: if that’s too small, some legend entries aren’t shown. How can the VBA code ‘see’|‘detect’|‘know’ that a height is too small?

Thank you.

PS: I expect that the correct answer is that “VBA cannot ‘see’|‘detect’|‘know’ either of these.” Please refute this expectation.

Comment: Check `.Legend.LegendEntries(1).Height`. If any wrapping occurs as you shrink the legend, there will be a sudden jump in this property.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own legend, using a text box, you have better options when it comes to sizing and flow control. This will create a new set of challenges, but it might be easier to handle.

Comment: Underneath a white rectangle, perhaps bordered. Within which lines, markers, and next to each of those a text box. As you say “a new set of challenges”, including that the TextFrame | TextFrame2 objects also don’t expose the presence of wrapping.

Comment: You can create bullets as characters and color them as text. That way you can remove the original legend all together.

Comment: “—•—”? Not beautiful.